# How do I mock a function from another package without using dependency injection?

Tags: unit-testing, testing, go

Somewhat of a golang beginner, but I've worked with testing frameworks before. How do I go about mocking out and faking what a dependent method returns without injecting the dependency? The reason why I don't want to use dependency injection is because there are many external package methods that are being used and injecting all of the methods in the constructor is unwieldy.

I've searched for this online/stackoverflow and the solution is to always use dependency injection. Sometimes that is not a viable option.

Here's what I'm trying to do code-wise:

b/b_test.go

```
package b

func TestResults(t *testing.T) {
    t.Run("Test", func(t *testing.T) {
        b := NewB()
        // How do I mock out and fake a.DoSomething() to be
        // "complete" instead of whats in the code right now?
        result = b.Results()
        assert.Equal(t, "complete", result)            
    }
}
```

b/b.go

```
package b

import "a"

type B struct {}

func NewB() B {
    return &B{}
}

func (b B) Results() {
    return a.DoSomething()
}
```

a/a.go

```
package a

func DoSomething() {
    return "done"
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: If you want to use mocks, your options are pretty much a) dependency injection, or b) service locator. The code using the mock has to get the mock from somewhere external that can make the decision on whether it gets a mock or a real implementation.

Comment: https://www.reddit.com/r/golang/comments/8jqjx8/dependency_injection_in_go/dz2pf5r/ and its Environment pattern could be an option: http://www.jerf.org/iri/post/2929

Comment: did you need to write a test Case of package b/b.go which having the implementation of a/a.go  you need to fake Your Call of a/a.go using Interface

Answer (score 17):

You can use [conditional compilation with build tags](https://golang.org/pkg/go/build/#hdr-Build_Constraints)

a/a.go

```
// +build !mock

package a
func DoSomething() {
    return "done"
}
```

a/a_mock.go

```
// +build mock

package a
func DoSomething() {  // Insert fake implementation here
    return "complete"
}
```

$ `go test -tags mock`

Comment: Good idea, but the tests are in package b, so that's probably where the mock / build tags should be.  Also, I think it's suspect to have to add flags `go test` to get correct tests.

Answer (score 6):

One way to do so would be to create a variable with the function you want to call, so include the following in b/b.go:

```
var doSomething = a.DoSomething
func (b B) Results() {
    return doSomething()
}
```

Now in b_test.go you can do this:

```
func TestPrintResults(t *testing.T) {
        origDoSomething := doSomething
        defer func() { doSomething = origDoSomething }
        doSomething = func() {
          // Insert fake implementation here
        }
        b := NewB()

        result = b.Results()

        assert.Equal(t, "complete", result)            
}
```

Comment: I would say it's a canonical way. It prevents Parallel() tests. It looks terrifyingly smelly if you come from heavy OO background. But in terms of readability it's optimal.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure if I don't understand your objection to dependency injection, but interfaces can be used to make dependency injection relatively painless. In particular **existing code does not need to be modified**.

You could try aliasing the package name to a global variable that implements an interface that matches the external package's functions. This has the advantage of not requiring inline changes where package "a" is used.

The idea revolves around creating an interface for the functions you need from the external package, a pass-through implementation of that interface for the default behavior and a mock implementation for testing. At the beginning of a test just replace the global variable with the mock.

b/a_interface.go

```
package b

import (
    aa "a" // alias the "a" package
)

// global variable that mimics the external package "a"
var a aType

// internal interface for `a` package functions (i.e. `DoSomething()`)
type aDoer interface {
    DoSomething() string
}

// default implementation of the aDoer interface
type aType struct{}

func (aType) DoSomething() string {
    // just pass-through to package "a"
    return aa.DoSomething()
}
```

b/b.go - is **unmodified** other then removing the import:

```
package b

type B struct{}

func NewB() B {
    return B{}
}

func (b B) Results() string{
    // now `a` is a global variable not a package.
    return a.DoSomething()  
}
```

b/b_test.go

```
package b

import (
    "testing"

    "github.com/stretchr/testify/assert"
)

// mock implementation of aDoer interface
type aMock struct{}

func (aMock) DoSomething() string {
    return "complete"
}

func TestResults(t *testing.T) {
    a = aMock{}  // <- replace the default with the mock

    b := NewB()

    result = b.Results()
    assert.Equal(t, "complete", result)            
}
```

It's a bit on the sneaky side, so you'll probably want to make clear comments about what's going on.

---

Comment: Small correction, in the file a_interface.go, instead of declaring `var a aType` you will need to define `var a = aDoer(aType{})` otherwise you won't be able to assign aMock to it.