# mocking and spying in golang without DI

Tags: unit-testing, go, mocking

Is there a way to mock and/or spy on methods in golang without using dependency injection.  For example lets say that I want to unit test the following method

```
import (
    "github.com/spf13/viper"
    "google.golang.org/grpc"
)

func startGrpcServer(ctx context.Context, wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
    defer wg.Done()

    listen, err := net.Listen("tcp", fmt.Sprintf(":%v", viper.GetString("GRPC_PORT")))
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    var opts []grpc.ServerOption
    grpcServer := grpc.NewServer(opts...)
    reflection.Register(grpcServer)
    s := health.NewHealthServer()
    proto.RegisterHealthServer(grpcServer, s)

    go func() {
        <-ctx.Done()
        log.Print("Stopping grpc server")
        grpcServer.GracefulStop()
    }()

    log.Print("Starting grpc server")
    grpcServer.Serve(listen)
}
```

I want to make sure of the following

1. The server is started (spying on the `grpcServer.Serve` method.
2. The environment value is ready from `viper.GetString` method.

As you can see the packages for these methods are global imports and I am not using DI.  Also this is legacy code so I cannot go and change all the code to support DI.  From my reading and initial researches done you cannot use mock/spy in golang without DI.  Is this correct ? or is there some way to do this ?

I came across the following but this is fairly dated [How do I mock a function from another package without using dependency injection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51428617/how-do-i-mock-a-function-from-another-package-without-using-dependency-injection) and from what I see in this, my options are fairly limited.

Comment: You can replace grpcServer without changing the function signature by using a [context value](https://golang.org/pkg/context/#WithValue). [Listeners have an Addr method](https://golang.org/pkg/net/#Listener) that returns their local address, reflecting the second argument to net.Listen.

Comment: Is your goal _not to change the code_, or simply _not to change the public API_?

Answer (score -1):

> Is there a way to mock and/or spy on methods in golang without using dependency injection.

No, there isn't.